# Python reduce opposite: generate values by invoking function on previous returned value

Tags: python, function, higher-order-functions

I am wondering if there is something opposite to reduce function in Python (2.7). I know reduce works like:

```
reduce( lambda x,y : x+y, [1,2,3,4,5]) == 15.
```

It takes first argument and second, and invokes function from first argument, then it takes result and next item in list and invokes the function again.

I want to do the opposite - generate list from one element. Something that would be:

```
reduce_opposite( lambda x: x**2, 3, n_times=3) == [(3 ** 2), (9 ** 2), (81 ** 2)]
```

Something that takes a function, an initial argument and `n` and takes this initial argument as input to function. Then store result in a list, and invoke function again but with result from previous invocation.

Is there something like this in Python? If not... just out of curiosity is there something like this in any language? What do you call it? I am looking for something very short. I can write my own function complicated which does this.

Comment: I too would like to know what the formal name for the "reduce_opposite" concept is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built in function to do this as far as I'm aware, but it's quite straightforward to write a generator (or something similar) to do the same trick. For example:

```
def reduce_opposite(fn, start, n_times=3):
    for _ in range(n_times):
        start = fn(start)
        yield start
```

Then:

```
>>> list(reduce_opposite(lambda x: x**2, 3, n_times=3))
[9, 81, 6561]
```

The fact that generators keep hold of their local variables between calls makes this possible.

Comment: Shouldn't `xrange(...)` be better than `range(...)` ?

Comment: If you're using Python 2 and `n_times` is not small, then `xrange` should replace `range ` in the code above, yes. (I think I was using Python 3 when I wrote this answer - there is no `xrange` there.)